# Why do we use rectangles rather than trapezia when performing integration?

Tags: integration

I've been familiar with integration, its motivation and its methods for a while know, but this question has only just entered my mind:

> When we integrate to find the area under a curve, why do we split up the curve into infinitesimally-thin **rectangles** rather than **trapezia**?

Surely, trapezia are more accurate to work with.

My motivation for this question is that a popular method for numerical integration, the trapezium rule, as its name suggests, splits the curve into arbitrarily-thin trapezia as opposed to rectangles.

So why is the integral defined as $$\int_{a}^{b}y(x)dx:=\lim_{\delta x \to 0} \sum_{x=a}^{b}y(x)\delta x \tag{sum of areas of rectangles}$$ rather than what appears to be the more-accurate $$\int_{a}^{b}y(x)dx:=\lim_{\delta x \to 0} \sum_{x=a}^{b}\frac{y(x)+y(x+1)}{2} \delta x \tag{sum of areas of trapezia}$$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are using "infinitely thin" shapes, rectangles and trapezia are equally accurate.  For numerical integration, however, you will be using shapes of a definite width, and in this case, generally speaking, trapezia will give a more accurate answer.  For some idea of what determines the accuracy of the trapezoidal approximation, you could start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114310).

Answer (score 2):

Both limits are the same for integrable functions, so it really makes no difference which one you take...

Also, as far as I know, the integral is defined as the limit of Riemann sums for which you can take any division of $[a,b]$ into as many subintervals as you want, so long as their longest one limits to $0$, and then take *any* set of values, one from each interval. So your definition is lacking.

Comment: So is it that we only use the first definition (as opposed to the second) because the first is simpler?

Comment: @alexqwx As I wrote in my edit, the "real" definition is more complicated than what you wrote.

Comment: See the wikipedia article for the proper definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_integral

Comment: @alexqwx Both definitions converge to the same value. The only difference really is the rate of convergence, which makes the trapezoidal rule more efficient for numerical algorithms.